# Calculating Correlation given Two discrete random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, correlation

Let $U$ and $V$ be discrete random variables with $U = −(V+1)/2$. What
is $Corr(U,V)$?

Do I substitute in $u$ as $(-v+1)$ and go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

We have

$$corr(U,V) = \frac{cov(U,V)}{\sqrt{DU \cdot DV}} = \frac{cov(-\frac{V+1}2,V)}{\sqrt{D(\frac{-V-1}{2}) \cdot DV}} = \frac{cov(-\frac{V}2,V)}{\sqrt{D(\frac{-V}{2}) \cdot DV}} =  \frac{-\frac12cov(V,V)}{\sqrt{\frac14 DV \cdot DV}} =$$
$$= \frac{-\frac12 DV}{\frac12 DV} = -1.$$

Comment: What i did was different but i still got -1, so what i did was sub in to get corr(-v-1,v) which gives us the form hypothetically corr(aX+b,Y) . In this case it shows that a<0. Which means its a negative value thus giving -1 as the correlation coefficient. Is this method a plausible way of doing this question too?

Comment: @Mathematician, I supposed that you have to prove all properties of $corr(X,Y)$. If you know that $corr(aX + b, Y) = sgn(a) corr(X,Y)$ then you may get the answer $-1$ immediately.